# Set Endpoint ID in ApiGateway for a private type using cloudformation in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, boto3, amazon-vpc

I am creating a template in YAML format for creating a stack. In api gateway i want to set a value for endpoint id in private type. is there a way i can do it in template? or can i do it using boto3?

ApiGateway:

```
Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
Properties:
  Description: A test API
  Name: !Ref ApiName
  EndpointConfiguration:
    Types:
      - "PRIVATE"
    vpcEndpointIds:
      - !Ref VPC
```

This code is giving error that there is no property vpcEndpointIds.

Comment: That's an open issue it appears that is yet to be resolved by the aws cloudformation team: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/186

Comment: Take a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration.html, but unfortunately the service would still complain `Encountered unsupported property VpcEndpointIds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudforamtion doesn't support it.This can be done using boto3 api gateway client:

```
client_api_gateway.update_rest_api(restApiId=self.api_id,
                                            patchOperations=[
                                                {
                                                    'op': 'add',
                                                    'path': '/endpointConfiguration/vpcEndpointIds',
                                                    'value': vpc_endpoint_id
                                                }
                                            ])
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration-vpcendpointids) document it seems it has now been added to `cloudformation`. However `aws-cdk` doesnt seem to reflect this update but the following (untested) code should get what you want, assuming the `cloudformation` docs reflect the current state.

```js
const api = new RestApi(this, 'APIGateway', {
    deploy: true,
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'live',
        tracingEnabled: true,
    },
    endpointTypes: [EndpointType.PRIVATE],
    retainDeployments: false,
    restApiName: 'my-api',
    description: 'an api',
});

const cfnApi = api.node.defaultChild as CfnMethod;

cfnApi.addOverride('Properties.EndpointConfiguration.VpcEndpointIds', ['12345']);
```

See here [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource_props) for details on adding missing features to constructs.